# Can you see a list of applications a company in the app store on the iphone?

Tags: iphone

I need to know if when someone accessed from the iPhone to app store, if he can filter the results to see the applications developed by a company.

Comment: Please don't repeat the question title again in the question body. Instead, be more verbose and explain what you want. I don't understand what you want from that single sentence...

Comment: Yes. 
Although, I'm not sure what I answered.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I've tried to explain it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to search for the name of a developer. But it's not possible to filter existing search results on the iPhone.

You can filter on the iPad, but not by company name.

Answer (score 1):

You can make html page with link like this:

```
<a href="itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/generalarcade">Games by General Arcade</a>
```

and if user clicks on it will open itunes app with filtered results for apps developed by General Arcade.

Answer (score 0):

Try you will have the answer. I think that it's possible.